Startup file works when submitted manually but not when the system starts
I have a file called startup.cmd in my Windows 10 startup directory called C:\Users\myuserid\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup.  The contents of the file are:
@echo off

echo Now mounting your disk drives

net use h: \\\\celerra03\exelhome\rbaumann /persistent:yes

net use s: \\\\celerra03\sas\stat /persistent:yes

net use Z: \\\\fsmain\userdata\_home /persistent:yes

echo Done mounting your disk drives

timeout 5

I use MobaXTerm to connect to this PC from another Windows 10 PC using Remote Desktop Protocol.
Whenever I log into the target PC I see the messages that are displayed by the echo instruction, so I know that the startup.cmd file is being found and executed.
However, for every NET USE instruction, Windows responds with a message saying error 85: the device is already in use. And if I open a Windows command prompt and enter one of the new Windows drive letters (followed by a colon), I see an error message indicating that the drive is not mounted.
However, if I then manually submit the startup.cmd file for execution, it works fine!  The specified drives are mounted and remain mounted within that Windows session.  Why would the net use commands work fine when manually submitted from within a cmd console but not at login time even though the echo instructions are correctly being displayed at logon time?

Have you tried deleting the mappings before (re)assigning them?

You stated the answer -- the drives are not yet mounted when the batch file is being executed at startup. Either delay execution until after all are mounted, or try using the UNC path rather than a drive letter -- see https://service.purdue.edu/TDClient/32/Purdue/KB/ArticleDet?ID=229

Hi all, I realized that I needed to provide some clarification to some parts of my original description but after I did so the system informed me that my comment was more than 2200 characters over the limit.  Apparently the original question can be described in a fair amount of detail but adding a comment to it after someone has responded to it can be no more than nine lines.  I guess I either have to cancel the question or resubmit it from scratch.  Sorry about that.

@fireblood Just EDIT your question !

@fireblood use the EDIT button to add info or clarification to your question. Edits and updates should not be comments down here. There's no need to delete this question or resubmit it, just use the tools already available. Perhaps reviewing the Help section may be of benefit to you as well, so that you better understand these available tools.

Before your first drive mapping in the batch script, add line net use /delete * /Y and then let it run the mappings. Another thought is your machine is allowing you to sign on before the network is fully established so you might be logging in before it is fully connected to the network. Here's a post with the group policy or reg settings to prevent this: Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon

Does it help if you specify a user in the command like:
net use N: \\192.168.1.50\whatever\path /USER:WHATEVER-NAS-NAME\someUser /PERSISTENT:YES 
(It would be a user on the NAS, not an account on the current Windows computer)

The reason you're getting error 85 when the startup script runs is because it's being run under the user level privilege. If the mapping already exists, the command will error.
When you run it as an administrator, it overrides the existing mapping with no error.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/system-error-85-net-use-command
This is correct behavior, and you don't need to make any changes.
For completeness also consider these:
You don't need the 4 slash marks in the beginning of your net use paths:
net use h: \\\\celerra03\exelhome\rbaumann /persistent:yes
also - make sure you're using ANSI encoding for your startup script.


Hi, I updated the startup.cmd file accordingly but am still encountering the same problems.

Error 85 means that the mapping already exists. If you specify /persistent:yes, that means the mapping doesn't need to be ran every login.
